# PerformancePoint filter

Tags: performancepoint

Hi 
I have created a performance point dashboard in which i have included a filter.
It works fine.
The filter has got parent nodes and child nodes.
For example...parent node is A
and its child node is 1,2,3
Again another parent node is B
and its child node is 1,2,3

so when i select the check box in front of A,it is showing  the graph according to the parent node A.
But I want the child nodes to be auto selected when ever i select the parent node,
i.e when i select the checkbox for A,its child nodes 1,2,3 should get auto selected and the graph should be displayed according to the child nodes.
Is this possible in performance point filter.

Plz help me out to solve this issue.
Thanks 
Sudipta Ghosh

Comment: Is this performancepoint 2010 or 2007?  I'll try to replicate in my environment.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, Performance Point does not allow you to check the child nodes from the parent level. Meaning you'll have to select each node you want to show onto the graph.